# Image transferred through TCP tends to be blank

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tcp, video-streaming, tcpserver

Im trying to transfer realtime feed between two devices. Following is my code for sending the image data to the client that the device is connected to. The server is a mobile device.

```
 WaitForEndOfFrame endOfFrame = new WaitForEndOfFrame();

IEnumerator senderCOR()
{

    bool isConnected = false;
    TcpClient client = null;
    NetworkStream stream = null;

    // Wait for client to connect in another Thread 
    Loom.RunAsync(() =>
    {
        while (!stop)
        {
            // Wait for client connection
            client = listner.AcceptTcpClient();
            // We are connected
            clients.Add(client);

            isConnected = true;
            stream = client.GetStream();
        }
    });

    //Wait until client has connected
    while (!isConnected)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    LOG("Connected!");

    bool readyToGetFrame = true;

    byte[] frameBytesLength = new byte[SEND_RECEIVE_COUNT];

    while (!stop)
    {
        //Wait for End of frame
        yield return endOfFrame;
        currentTexture.SetPixels(backCam.GetPixels());
        byte[] pngBytes = currentTexture.EncodeToPNG();
        //Fill total byte length to send. Result is stored in frameBytesLength
        byteLengthToFrameByteArray(pngBytes.Length, frameBytesLength);
        string savePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "ph.png");
        saveImage(savePath,pngBytes);
        //Set readyToGetFrame false
        readyToGetFrame = false;

        Loom.RunAsync(() =>
        {


            //Send total byte count first
            stream.Write(frameBytesLength, 0, frameBytesLength.Length);
            LOG("Sent Image byte Length: " + frameBytesLength.Length);

            //Send the image bytes
            stream.Write(pngBytes, 0, pngBytes.Length);
            LOG("Sending Image byte array data : " + pngBytes.Length);

            //Sent. Set readyToGetFrame true
            readyToGetFrame = true;
        });

        //Wait until we are ready to get new frame(Until we are done sending data)
        while (!readyToGetFrame)
        {
            LOG("Waiting To get new frame");
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the image that "ph.png" which is the saved image is always an empty image. It is supposed to be the feed from the camera. How can I be able to sort this out?

Comment: I dont have a camera to check on, so, save at the one end as a debug to prove to yourself the file being sent was valid then you can compare what you got to the other end more to see how what you received was different

Comment: images from both ends are being empty

Comment: then you need to work out how to fix the local end before you send it the remote seems to be getting what you sent.